# Recording samples in IOS

Tags: ios, audio, record

I want to make an app like http://itunes.apple.com/us/app/conga-drums-free/id473562183?mt=8 .

users can make their own beats. I want to record their beats while playing or later and save it.Then send it to server. There are too many examples about recording from mic but I didn't find anything about recording output sound in IOS.

Comment: don't expect people to just give out code for an entire app here.

Answer (score 0):

You're going have to learn to handle CoreAudio. Although there is a good framework designed for taking the pain away from doing that called [novocaine](https://github.com/alexbw/novocaine). Makes it as simple as (from the frameworks documentation)

```
Novocaine *audioManager = [Novocaine audioManager];
[audioManager setInputBlock:^(float *newAudio, UInt32 numSamples, UInt32 numChannels) {
    // Now you're getting audio from the microphone every 20 milliseconds or so. How's that for easy?
    // Audio comes in interleaved, so,
    // if numChannels = 2, newAudio[0] is channel 1, newAudio[1] is channel 2, newAudio[2] is channel 1, etc.
}];
```

And if you're interested in having finer control, looking at the source code for the framework will be a good place start. Once you have acquired the data, you can use a framework like [AFNetworking](https://github.com/AFNetworking/AFNetworking) to upload the data to a server.

Answer (score 0):

We can do it in 2 ways either using AVfoundation or CoreAudio.

I haven't explored coreAudio but in AVfoundation its pretty simple. using this blog...
http://www.techotopia.com/index.php/Recording_Audio_on_an_iPhone_with_AVAudioRecorder_%28iOS_4%29